# Typo3 custom form translation seems to read some default values

Tags: typo3, typo3-extensions, language-translation

I'm new to typo3. I'm trying to translate some of my custom forms to other languages. Forms are made in Form extension for typo3.

Here is my example form i took from some tutorial just for test purposes:

```
renderingOptions:
  translation:
    translationFiles:
      20: 'EXT:form/Resources/Private/Language/de.locallang.xlf'
  submitButtonLabel: Submit
identifier: MyForm
label: 'My form example'
type: Form
prototypeName: standard
finishers:
  -
    options:
      subject: 'Message from your website'
      recipientAddress: your.company@example.com
      recipientName: 'Your Company name'
      senderAddress: '{email}'
      senderName: '{lastname}'
      replyToAddress: ''
      carbonCopyAddress: ''
      blindCarbonCopyAddress: ''
      format: html
      attachUploads: true
    identifier: EmailToReceiver
  -
    options:
      message: 'Thank you for your message! We will get back to you as soon as possible.'
    identifier: Confirmation
renderables:
  -
    renderingOptions:
      previousButtonLabel: 'Previous step'
      nextButtonLabel: 'Neue Seite'
    identifier: page-1
    label: 'Contact Form'
    type: Page
    renderables:
      -
        properties:
          options:
            male: Mr
            female: Ms
          prependOptionLabel: 'Please choose ...'
          fluidAdditionalAttributes:
            required: required
        type: SingleSelect
        identifier: title
        label: Title
        validators:
          -
            identifier: NotEmpty
      -
        defaultValue: ''
        identifier: lastname
        label: 'Last name'
        type: Text
        properties:
          fluidAdditionalAttributes:
            placeholder: 'Your last name'
        validators:
          -
            identifier: NotEmpty
      -
        defaultValue: ''
        identifier: subject
        label: Subject
        type: Text
        properties:
          fluidAdditionalAttributes:
            placeholder: Subject
        validators:
          -
            identifier: NotEmpty
      -
        defaultValue: ''
        identifier: email
        label: Email
        type: Text
        properties:
          fluidAdditionalAttributes:
            placeholder: 'Email address'
        validators:
          -
            identifier: NotEmpty
          -
            identifier: EmailAddress
      -
        defaultValue: ''
        identifier: message
        label: Message
        type: Textarea
        properties:
          fluidAdditionalAttributes:
            placeholder: ''
        validators:
          -
            identifier: NotEmpty
  -
    renderingOptions:
      previousButtonLabel: 'Previous step'
      nextButtonLabel: 'Neue Seite'
    identifier: summarypage
    label: 'Summary page'
    type: SummaryPage
```

as you can see i've added a path to custom language

```
renderingOptions:
  translation:
    translationFiles:
      20: 'EXT:form/Resources/Private/Language/de.locallang.xlf'
```

and here is my `de.locallang.xlf` file

```
<trans-unit id="element.lastname.properties.placeholder" approved="yes">
    <source>Your last name</source>
    <target>some random translation</target>
</trans-unit>
```

The problem is that Typo3 seems to read some default german translations instead of custom translations i've made as you can see here;

[typo3 translated form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHvFi.png)

There is no such translations in my project directory in any place.

How i can get my custom translations to work?

Typo v.10.4.36
Form plugin v.10.4.36

I've tried to work it out with guide like [forms translate tutorial](https://www.sebkln.de/en/tutorials/translating-forms-in-the-typo3-form-framework/#translations)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need two translation files:

- locallang.xlf for the English (default) labels
- de.locallang.xlf for the German translations

Then load the **default** translation file in `translationFiles`. TYPO3 will automatically search for your German XLIFF file.

```
renderingOptions:
  translation:
    translationFiles:
      20: 'EXT:your_sitepackage/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf'
```

Please also check the path to your locallang.xlf file. In your example, EXT:form was used. This is the TYPO3 core extension, you must use your own extension name (and path) here.

If you get German labels that were not configured by yourself, I think you installed the "form_examples" demo extension. In that case, the translations of this extensions are loaded. Try to use a higher key number for your own `translationFiles` entry (or uninstall the demo extension).

Comment: Thanks! I was lacking my own extension for this to work :)